Azure Synapse data exfiltration protection issue
Data Exfiltration Protection is enabled on one of our Synapse Workspace. In a notebook, a python script must get a token from Entra ID in order to authenticate to another Azure Service to send data to.
There is an issue to connect to client authentication endpoint:

ClientAuthenticationError: Authentication failed:
(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f89bbfb11e0>,
'Connection to login.microsoftonline.com timed out. (connect
timeout=300)')

The method used is:
credential = ClientSecretCredential(azure_tenant_id, azure_client_id, azure_client_secret)

On other Synapse workspaces on which Data Exfiltration Protection is not enabled, we do not face this issue, leading to the fact that this protection could be the cause of the problem.
Do you have any history and/or idea about that?

ERROR:

ClientAuthenticationError: Authentication failed:
(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f89bbfb11e0>,
'Connection to login.microsoftonline.com timed out. (connect
timeout=300)')

ERROR message says Data Exfiltration Protection is blocking the connection to the Azure Active Directory (Entra ID) authentication endpoint.

As you mentioned that you are not facing the issue on other Synapse workspaces on which Data Exfiltration Protection is not enabled
You can try on Synapse workspaces on which Data Exfiltration Protection is enabled using a different authentication method that does not require outbound traffic, such as a managed identity or a certificate-based authentication.
These methods do not rely on outbound traffic and may work better with the Data Exfiltration Protection feature enabled.
Know more bout the ClientSecretCredential Class:
Authenticates as a service principal using a client secret.
Inheritance
azure.identity._internal.client_credential_base.ClientCredentialBase 
ClientSecretCredential

